# How to grant ssh access for another user onto an elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can go eb ssh.
I can't though work out what the ssh command on it's own would be.
I want my colleague to be able to ssh in.
They have an AWS account.
What page in the doco should I be following ?.

edit:
I actually want them to be able to go `eb deploy` so basically how do you set up eb to use someone else's system ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS allows you to delegate access to a user in another AWS account so that he can work with your resources. See [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html), [Delegating Access Across Accounts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/walkthru_cross-account-with-roles.html), and [IAM Roles with Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html).

Alternatively, you could simply create an IAM user in your account with the relevant permissions and then give those credentials to your colleague. Roles and cross-account access are generally the preferred method, however.

Comment: delegating access, exactly. I'll tick once I worked it out and post any hints.